# How do I create a legend for a bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How do I create legends like the following:

[image]

So far I have the following:

[image]

I can't figure out how to specify labels for the legend. They don't provide examples either.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

So far I have the following code:

```
var topClickSourcesChart = new Chart('dashboard-click-source-chart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Facebook","Google","NONE",],
      datasets: [{
        data: [10,5,3,],
        backgroundColor: ['#4D90C3', '#866DB2', '#EA6F98', '#61BDF6', '#768BB7'],
      }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
                boxWidth: 10,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show a legend you need to set the `label` property of a `dataset`, so the type of output you are expecting can be built by creating a chart from the code as shown below. Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/6nkcx8sq/

```
var topClickSourcesChart = new Chart('dashboard-click-source-chart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Number of users"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Facebook',
        data: [10],
        backgroundColor: '#4D90C3',
      },
      {
        label: 'Instagram',
        data: [15],
        backgroundColor: '#866DB2',
      },
      {
        label: 'Twitter',
        data: [7],
        backgroundColor: '#EA6F98',
      }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
                boxWidth: 10,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes it difficult to write a loop for the data if the `backgroundColor` has to be part of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it with the following, but it was a pain in the ass for loops due to the `backgroundColor` having to be inside the `dataset`.

```
var topClickSourceChart = new Chart('dashboard-click-source-chart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Facebook","Google","NONE",],
      datasets: [
          {label: "Facebook", data: [10]},{label: "Google", data: [5]},{label: "NONE", data: [3]},
      ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
                boxWidth: 10,
            }
        }
    }
});
if (topClickSourceChart.data.datasets.length > 0) topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = '#4D90C3';
if (topClickSourceChart.data.datasets.length > 1) topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[1].backgroundColor = '#866DB2';
if (topClickSourceChart.data.datasets.length > 2) topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[2].backgroundColor = '#EA6F98';
if (topClickSourceChart.data.datasets.length > 3) topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[3].backgroundColor = '#61BDF6';
if (topClickSourceChart.data.datasets.length > 4) topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[4].backgroundColor = '#768BB7';
```

Here is the JSP/JSTL loop:

```
data: {
  labels: [<c:forEach items="${clickSources}" var="cs">"${cs.key}",</c:forEach>],
  datasets: [
      <c:forEach items="${clickSources}" var="cs">{label: "${cs.key}", data: [${cs.value}]},</c:forEach>
  ]
},
```

I still could not find a way to make the top of the bars rounded.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to round bars with chart.js, but you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts). you can add `cornerRadius: 20` to options then, just copy js files in your project and include them.

Comment: @Alien Neat! But it also makes the bottom corners round too. No way to specify `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius`, etc.