# How can I change the background colors of a bar chart after it has been created?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, chart.js

How can I change the colors of a bar chart after it has been created? I have the following.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoboRg?editors=1010#0

```js
// can't move to home.js because the label is dynamic
var topClickSourceChart = new Chart('dashboard-click-source-chart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      datasets: [
       {label: "NONE", data: [14]},{label: "Facebook", data: [10]},{label: "Google", data: [5]},{label: "Reddit", data: [1]},{label: "Twitter", data: [1]},
      ]
    },
});
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = '#4D90C3';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[1].backgroundColor = '#866DB2';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[2].backgroundColor = '#EA6F98';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[3].backgroundColor = '#61BDF6';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[4].backgroundColor = '#768BB7';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-MZo5XY1Ah7Z2Aui4/alkfeiq3CopMdV/bbkc/Sh41+s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas id="dashboard-click-source-chart" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
```

[It used to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54878773/148844). I don't understand what changed, especially since I have a resource integrity hash attribute.

It seems to work in a Full Page snippet here, but not in a small snippet, and it doesn't work in CodePen, and it doesn't work on my local site.

Why would it ignore the background color on some sites but not others?

Comment: you simply need to redraw the thing .. that's why it work on full snippet because you trigger the drawing again

Comment: @TemaniAfif How do you redraw? I can't find that function in the API. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html

Comment: Yes, resizing the window does make the colors appear.

Comment: I was trying below to trigger the resize event but not working

Answer (score 1):

I found the `.update()` function.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

I just had to add

```
topClickSourceChart.update();
```

Funny how it worked sometimes but not others, depending on the size of the window.

```js
// can't move to home.js because the label is dynamic
var topClickSourceChart = new Chart('dashboard-click-source-chart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      datasets: [
       {label: "NONE", data: [14]},{label: "Facebook", data: [10]},{label: "Google", data: [5]},{label: "Reddit", data: [1]},{label: "Twitter", data: [1]},
      ]
    },
});
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = '#4D90C3';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[1].backgroundColor = '#866DB2';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[2].backgroundColor = '#EA6F98';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[3].backgroundColor = '#61BDF6';
topClickSourceChart.data.datasets[4].backgroundColor = '#768BB7';
topClickSourceChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-MZo5XY1Ah7Z2Aui4/alkfeiq3CopMdV/bbkc/Sh41+s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas id="dashboard-click-source-chart" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
```